# What's the matter, logic, reason?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in programming, and I started my journey with Python. In my view, as shown below in the code block, the output to be come does matter, like, I used to think multiple type variables couldn't be wrote in one single line of code, but after having this exercise from one of the sources I learn from, I changed my view. This is because the code's output wouldn't have any other variable type rather than than string, so the line of code was right. Is this view right, or is it some different case?

---

Programming language= Python(version 3), IDE: PyCharm

Below  is the code:

---

```
print("I said " + ("Hey "*2) + "Hey!")
print("I said "+"Hey "*2+"Hey!")
print("I said"+" Hey"*3+"!")
```

---

Below is the output:

```
I said Hey Hey Hey!

I said Hey Hey Hey!

I said Hey Hey Hey!
```

Comment: They're all strings. `"foo" * 42` with or without the superfluous parentheses returns a string.

Comment: How is it related to IDE? What is actually the problem (I could not understand it from the OP, sorry)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel That was the confusion there, in the code multiplying a string by a numeric value(int here), so, and as per my knowledge was, multiple types of values couldn't be wrote together in one single line of code. Well, if I guess right, based on my knowledge right now, that was 'operator overloading'. Thank you for giving your time in this post of mine, thanks.

Comment: @JanStránský Stránský That was a  hashtag not related, so, yeah, no case with IDE. The problem was  as per my knowledge was, multiple types of values couldn't be wrote together in one single line of code. Well, if I guess right, based on my knowledge right now, that was 'operator overloading'. Thank you for giving your time in this post of mine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Python has by default overloaded operators for the `+` and `*` operations. That means that these operators have specific definitions for the string class, in this case, concat for `+` and n concat of the same string for `"string"*n`
Here is more information about [Operator overloading in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/)